# Plotting LISA map using R

Tags: r, plot

I want to draw the following LISA map using `LISA` plot:

[image]

I have coded as follow:

```
o1<-California_shp$houseValue
o1
 [1] 208747.39 118700.00 117146.43  89611.54 107893.75  77731.25 216783.78
 [8]  97163.64 145876.67  84680.57  72276.88  89362.60  74405.08 100794.39
[15]  81421.08  76828.41  93896.55  76176.00 237163.15  85700.00 355758.13
[22] 100177.78 120720.00  93139.06  51162.50 152129.41 226799.51 204133.01
[29] 151272.92 254876.92 171049.24  97109.09 140104.60 131881.10 216078.57
[36] 126713.36 194194.35 337972.47 121807.89 212139.69 350042.94 251899.02
[43] 302819.04 255027.12  90765.29  77887.50  68205.41 147259.80 205761.74
[50] 129957.89  95244.64  73006.12  70718.48  78767.05 124328.07 251974.24
[57] 140881.01  78558.49

neigh1<-poly2nb(California_shp,queen=TRUE)
neigh1
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 58 
Number of nonzero links: 276 
Percentage nonzero weights: 8.204518 
Average number of links: 4.758621

listw1<-nb2listw(neigh1,style = "B")
listw1
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 58 
Number of nonzero links: 276 
Percentage nonzero weights: 8.204518 
Average number of links: 4.758621 

Weights style: B 
Weights constants summary:
   n   nn  S0  S1   S2
B 58 3364 276 552 5752

moran(o1,listw1,S0=Szero(listw1),n=length(neigh))$I
[1] 0.06761524
local1<-localmoran(o1,listw1)
head(local1)
         Ii       E.Ii   Var.Ii      Z.Ii  Pr(z > 0)
1 4.0597758 -0.0877193 4.466689 1.9624248 0.02485652
2 0.4033954 -0.0877193 4.466689 0.2323754 0.40812323
3 0.5311378 -0.0877193 4.466689 0.2928178 0.38483070
4 3.7039811 -0.1052632 5.261654 1.6606483 0.04839205
5 0.7905368 -0.0877193 4.466689 0.4155548 0.33886790
6 2.7982894 -0.0877193 4.466689 1.3655411 0.08604152
```

I want to use the following method:

```
source(LISA.R)
LISA.plot(y=California_shp$houseValue,sp=California_shp,local1)
```

But I do not know how to find `LISA.R`. The output message in R is:

```
source(LISA.R)
Error in source(LISA.R) : object 'LISA.R' not found
```

So how can I find the data of `LISA.R`?

Should I download `LISA.R` of California from the internet or I have to write codes to create `LISA.R`?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The `source` function runs code from another R script file (see `help(source)` for details).

Normally you'd see it more like:

```
source("LISA.R")
```

with the filename in quotation marks. Without the quotation marks it tries to find the *value* of an R object called `LISA.R`. That's why the error is `object 'LISA.R' not found`. You don't have an R object with that name.

To load a *file* with that name, use `source("LISA.R")`. If that file isn't found you'll get:

```
> source("LISA.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'LISA.R': No such file or directory
```

If you don't have a file called `LISA.R` then you'll have to ask whoever or wherever told you to do this where it should be.